# one drive vs one drive for buisness graph api and login endpoint

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

is there a one login end point for one drive and one drive for business, like https://login.windows.net used for one drive for business, is there any similar end point for both. 2) does graph API support accessing files in one drive , i know it support for one drive for business.

i have tried using graph API for one drive but that didn't not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a converged auth flow that supports getting tokens for users in the commercial and consumer service, it is called v2.0 auth endpoint. To use it you need to register your app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and follow the instructions here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth. Then your app would be able to use the Microsoft Graph to access both OneDrive and OneDrive for Business, as well as Outlook.com and Office365 Exchange functionality.

Comment: seems like an answer, let me create the sample application and update you..thanks.